# Extract Data from Google Map Result

Tags: google-maps

I want to create a custom application that aggregates locations I find using Google maps into a custom map.   For a couple of reasons, google's save to map feature is insufficient for my needs.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can create a browser extension that will let me pop up a custom form and then transmit the form data and the lon/lat data to my own server.

I can figure out most of the pieces of this myself, except for extracting the longitude and latitude data.  Is this stored anywhere in the dom or window object that I can query when looking at a marker or the location details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use google map event listener to get coordinate data.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
var pos;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {        
  pos = map.getCenter();
});
```

You can get the latitude using `pos.lat()` and `pos.lng()` for the longitude